# Python TypeError: int() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python

I am trying to write a simple hangman game in python but is getting this error. Not sure where the error is coming from. I appreciate any help. Thank you.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-323840294aea> in <module>
      8 seconds = 60
      9 
---> 10 class engine(seconds):
     11         import getpass
     12         word=getpass.getpass("please enter a secret word")

TypeError: int() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Code:

Comment: Why are you creating 2 classes with same name and parameters ```engine(seconds)```? Also, using class makes no sense here. You should use functions

Comment: Why did you edit your code out of the question?

Answer (score 1):

You have a global `int` variable named `seconds` that you are attempting to derive your classes from. I suspect you intended them to be functions, which requires `def` not `class`, e.g.:

```
def engine(seconds):
```

However, you also have multiple classes/functions named the same thing so you will also need to resolve that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use classes for that. Instead, use `def` keyword and define the function with the `seconds` parameter. You are trying to derive a class from an integer.

Also, you have 2 `engine` "classes". The second definition will overwrite the first one. So you will have to change that.

```
def engine(seconds)
```